# Proving Two Statements on Independence and Mutual Exclusion

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, independence

**GIVEN $P(A)>0$ and $P(B)>0$.**

> If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then they cannot be mutually exclusive.

My proof:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent sets such that $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)>0 $. 
$$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)>0$$
Now suppose that $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=0$$
But this is a contradiction, as $\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)>0$ by design.
Hence $A$ and $B$ cannot be mutually exclusive.

> If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then they cannot be independent.

My proof:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets such that $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)>0 $. If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then
 $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=0$$
Now suppose $A$ and $B$ are independent, then
$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A)=0 \ \ \  \text{and/or} \ \ \ \mathbb{P}(B)=0$$
But this is a contradiction, as $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)>0$ by design. Hence $A$ and $B$ cannot be independent.

Are these proofs correct? I have tried to make them simple, but are they too simple that they fail to prove each relevant statement?

Comment: Your statement is not true unless you claim $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ to be positive what you did later.
So: Under your additional assumption  $P(A)P(B) > 0$ the proof is correct. But then you should also mention these assumptions in your original statement. 
Because in general it's false hence there are (non-trivial) sets $A$ with $P(A) = 0$

Comment: So I should include the case where $P(A)=0$ for completeness? How can this be achieved?

Comment: Two statements?? No, only one. If $i$ stands for independent and $e$ for mutually exclusive then $i\implies\neg e$ is the same as $e\implies\neg i$. As @Gono comments: let $a$ denote the statement that $P(A)P(B)>0$. Then you proved twice that $a\implies\neg[i\wedge e]$.

Comment: Okay. I wrote it out as two separate statements as this is how it was present in an exam paper. But I do agree with what you're saying.

Comment: I shall amend my question. Please note my first line in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proofs are correct, but as a matter of style, I would recommend saying "Now suppose [...] by contradiction" to emphasize that you're doing a proof by contradiction.